# Entity Framework Parent\Child Retrieval

Tags: entity

I have an ID of a "Component" parent record that I need to retrieve all the "Attachment" child records.   The grid I am using need fields returned an placed in "TheComponentAttachmentsJoinedTable"  I am only able to retrieve one record.  I have used the value of FirstorDefault.  That is the only way it will accept the line of code without complaining about the IEnumerable  to int.   Could someone please explain what is incorrect?

```
public class Component
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ComponentCode { get; set; }
    public string ComponentDescription { get; set; }
    public double ComponentWeight { get; set; }
    public double ComponentQuantity { get; set; }
    public string LastModUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentDescription { get; set; }
    public string OriginalName { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public byte[] bytes { get; set; }
    public string LastModUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModDate { get; set; }

    //Navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Element> Elements { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }  //lt M-m
}


public class TheComponentAttachmentsJoinedTable
{
    public int ComponentID { get; set; }
    public int AttachmentID { get; set; }
    public string OriginalName { get; set; }
}

public static List<TheComponentAttachmentsJoinedTable>   ComponentAttachments_GetAllByComponentID(int ComponentID)
    {
        using (TheContext TheDB = new TheContext())
        {
           var r = (from x in TheDB.Component
        .Where(x => x.ID == ComponentID)
        .Include(x => x.Attachments)
                     select new TheComponentAttachmentsJoinedTable
                    {
                        ComponentID = x.ID,
                        AttachmentID = x.Attachments.Select(y => (y.ID)).FirstOrDefault(),
                        OriginalName = x.Attachments.Select(y => y.OriginalName).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
                    }
     );
return r.ToList();
}
```